# How to keep an object flat relative to the camera?

Tags: animation, camera, transforms, constraints, transform-orientation

I'm trying to create a 2D look for an animation and found that the lighting came out really nicely when I flattened my model the same way the camera was facing.[image: Matte image of the Kool-Aid man running in a cartoon artstyle.][image: Same Kool-Aid man pose in the earlier image shown from a different angle revealing the camera and the model flattened relative to it along with the Blender UI showing the scale settings]

However I don't want my model to just be facing the camera the entire time and don't know how to rotate it while keeping the same flattened scale relative to the camera.
[image: Distorted image of the Kool-Aid man running][image: Second perspective of the Kool-Aid man image showing the model rotated no longer parallel with the camera along with the Blender UI showing the rotation settings.]

Is there any way I can get the model to stay flat towards the camera? Don't ask about the Kool-Aid man and sorry if the post is unclear. Still kinda new to Blender.

Comment: This could well be a duplicate. See if the search-term 'Billboard' helps you on this site. There are a few approaches, depending on your set-up. Let us know if any of the answers there are good for you. If not, edit to explain what else you need.